# Unable to write jooq query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am not able to write above query in JOOQ .

Here is my postgres query

```
select aps.agent_id,aps.stats_date from application as aps
    join (
        select max(stats_date) as stats_date, agent_id
        from  application
        group by application.agent_id, date(application.stats_date)) temp
    on temp.stats_date = aps.stats_date and temp.agent_id = aps.agent_id and aps.stats_date > current_date - interval '30' day;
```

Mainly finding difficult in 2 places 
1) Assigning  result of subquery to temp table
2) Getting last 30 days result : current_date - interval '30' day

Answer (score 1):

#### 1) Assigning result of subquery to temp table

Given that jOOQ is an internal DSL in Java, you cannot inline your derived table directly where you're using it, but you'll have to declare it up front, before your statement:

```java
Table<?> temp = table(
  select(
    max(APPLICATION.STATS_DATE).as(APPLICATION.STATS_DATE),
    APPLICATION.AGENT_ID
  )
  .from(APPLICATION)
  .groupBy(APPLICATION.AGENT_ID, date(APPLICATION.STATS_DATE));
```

Now you can join the `temp` table and extract columns from it using:

```java
Field<Date> tempStatsDate = temp.field(APPLICATION.STATS_DATE);
```

#### 2) Getting last 30 days result : current_date - interval '30' day

Day intervals can be created easily by subtracting integers from your date columns, e.g.

```java
currentDate().minus(30)
```

Or using an interval:

```java
currentDate().minus(new DayToSecond(30))
```

Of course, you can also use [`DSL.dateSub()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#dateSub(java.sql.Date,java.lang.Number))

```java
dateSub(currentDate(), 30)
```

Comment: Thank you . Great explanation